# Attempting to export a file from C#, via Javascript/Ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I am having an issue while attempting to export a file. When a button is clicked, a Javascript function is called that gets information from all of the div tags with a certain class, and then does an Ajax call to a Post method in the C# code. This portion works fine until the Post is returned, as all divs are returned and all parameters are passed in correctly:

```
$("#btnTest").on("click", function () {
    var selectedSurveyID = $("#surveySelectDrpDwn").val();
    var instanceID = $("#InstanceID").val();
    var cycleID = $("#CycleID").val();
    var userID = $("#UserID").val();

    //var thePage = $("html").html();
    var htmlList = [];
    var htmlList2 = [];

    $(".printQuestionPreviewLabel").each(function (i, v) {
        htmlList2.push(v.outerHTML);
    }
    );
    $(".printPreviewLabel").each(function (i, v) {
        htmlList.push(v.outerHTML);
    }
    );
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/Export2API/getPDF2",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            selectedSurveyID: $("#surveySelectDrpDwn").val()
                               , instanceID: $("#InstanceID").val()
                               , cycleID: $("#CycleID").val()
                               , userID: $("#UserID").val()
                               , ResponseList: htmlList
                               , QuestionList: htmlList2
                               , IsFileListResponse: false
        }),
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (errMsg) {
            console.log('Error');
            console.log(errMsg);
            //alert(errMsg);
        }
});
```

In a separate C# file, this is the post method -

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage getPDF2(PDFViewModel pvm)
    {
        ExportService exsv = new ExportService();
        exsv.getPDF(pvm);

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "test");
    }
```

and the subsequent function that it calls.

```
    public void getPDF(PDFViewModel pvm)
    {

        List<string> rList = pvm.ResponseList;
        string htmlString = "";


        foreach (string item in rList)
        {
            htmlString = htmlString + item + "</br>";
        }

        Document doc = new Document();
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memoryStream);
        doc.Open();
        doc.Add(new Paragraph(htmlString));
        writer.CloseStream = false;
        doc.Close();
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        memoryStream.Close();

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = false;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "Application/octet-stream";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf" );
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```

The Response section in the last brick should, according to my colleagues and various sources online, write the information to a pdf and then export it as a download. This is not happening.

When the button is clicked, all information is passed through, the document is created, the MemoryStream acts as expected, but there is no download, no prompt for one, and it just finishes and does nothing. I would be grateful for any assistance in this matter.

Comment: I would guess that you are overriting the httpContext.Current.Responst by the line return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "test");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "test");
```

This is returning a 200 OK content-type of text/plain response with a value of "test". You need it to return a content-type of application/pdf and the value equal to your PDF's data.

You're trying to send the response in getPDF. Have getPDF return the byte array instead and return the response. Writing and sending the response should be the last thing you do, I believe you were sending a second response that took priority over the PDF response you made.

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage getPDF2(PDFViewModel pvm)
{
    ExportService exsv = new ExportService();
    byte[] data = exsv.getPDF(pvm);

    Response response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Buffer = false;
    response.Clear();
    response.ClearContent();
    //response.ClearHeaders(); //You want the 200 OK Headers
    response.ContentType = "Application/octet-stream";
    response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf" );
    response.BinaryWrite(data);
    response.Flush();
    response.End(); //I don't know if you need this
    return response;
}
```

I'm not familiar with C# and response objects, so I apologize if the method names are not correct, but this should be enough of a direction for you to go on.

Comment: This seems to be what the issue is, as far as I can tell, thank you. I will try to figure out the syntax for the Responses, if anyone has any insight it would be greatly appreciated.